# Accessing <div> elements by name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following content in  -

```
var jsonObj = [ {"name" : "Jason"},{"name":"Bourne"},{"name":"Peter"},{"name":"Marks"}];

<!---->

$("#getname").click(function() {
    var response = getNames(jsonObj);
    $("#nameData").html(response);
});

function getNames(jsonObj){
    var response  = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    for ( var i = 0, len = jsonObj.length; i < len; i++) {
        var nameVal =  jsonObj[i].name;
        response = response.replace(nameVal,replaceTxt(nameVal,i));
    }
    return response;
}

function replaceTxt(nameVal,cnt){
    return "<u id='"+cnt+"' name='names' >"+nameVal+"</u> ";
}

$('u[name="names"]').dblclick(function(){
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(currentId);
    });
});
```

and html as below -

```
<button id="getname">Get Name</button>
<div id="nameData"></div>
```

Double clicking on names value doesn't generating alerts.

Comment: To save people time, always post code on jsfiddle it will be quicker for everyone :)

Comment: You don't need the last "});"

Answer (score 1):

are you sure it is..

```
 <dev id="nameData"></dev>
```

OR

```
<div id="nameData"></div>
```

this works...but you have an extra `});` in the question...(don't know if it is a typo)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ur5cD/1/) here

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('u[name="names"]').live("dblclick", function(){
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(currentId);
    });
});
```

Comment: @PaddyREC **plz note:** `.live()` is now removed in jQuery version 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this code:

```
$('u[name="names"]').dblclick(function(){
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(currentId);
    });
});
```

inside

```
$("#getname").click(function() {
    var response = getNames(jsonObj);
    $("#nameData").html(response);
});
```

like:

```
$("#getname").click(function() {
    var response = getNames(jsonObj);
    $("#nameData").html(response);
$('u[name="names"]').dblclick(function(){
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(currentId);
    });
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the last "`});`" Or you didn't paste the whole code.

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/4cajw/1/

Answer (score 0):

As your code suggest that you are `.dblclick()`ing on dynamically generated element, that don't work, `you have to select parent elem which exist in the document`

```
$(document).on('dblclick','u[name="names"]', function(){
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(currentId);
});
```

try this out.

Comment: i don't think this is the case since... you can only  doubleclick the element only after it is appended in the dom either it is dynamic or watever....

Comment: yes this happens when you apply events directly on dynamically generated elemnts.

Answer (score -1):

JSON.stringify - object -> JSON.

JSON.parse - JSON -> object

Comment: sorry, I thought that `jsonObj` should be string.

Comment: Just explain your answer fluently so people would understand what do you mean :)